# Raising an error when creating an object in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, class, exception

My problem isn't really a specific question, but an unexpected behaviour from my program. I am trying to build a class **Node** that I will later on use to build a class **Tree** to build tree structures of the folders, subfolders and files of a given directory.

Currently, I am building the class **Node**.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, path):
        """Assumes path is a string"""
        self.path = (path, path[:-1])[path.endswith('/')]
        self.name = os.path.basename(self.path)
        if os.path.isdir(self.path):
            self.type = 'Directory'
        elif os.path.isfile(self.path):
            self.type = 'File'
        else:
            raise OSError ('Path is incorrect. It does not lead to a file, nor to a directory')

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getPath(self):
        return self.path

    def getType(self):
        return self.type

    def getInfo(self):
        print(self.type + ' ' + self.name + ' : ' + self.path)

    def getParent(self):
        return Node(os.path.dirname(self.path))

    def getChilds(self, hidden = False):
        return [Node(os.path.join(self.path, child)) for child 
                in os.listdir(self.path) if (child[0] != '.' or hidden)]

    def __str__(self):
        return '<' + self.type + ',' + self.name + '>'
```

Running :

```
CEA = Node('/Users/alexandrejewell/Desktop/CEA/')
for child in CEA.getChilds():
    child.getInfo()

>>> Directory Database : /Users/alexandrejewell/Desktop/CEA/Database
     : /Users/alexandrejewell/Desktop/CEA/Icon
    Directory VSA : /Users/alexandrejewell/Desktop/CEA/VSA
    Directory Inputs : /Users/alexandrejewell/Desktop/CEA/Inputs
```

The *Icon* file isn't a valid file and should raise an error when creating its corresponding node, just as it does when instantiating it directly:

```
Icon = Node('/Users/alexandrejewell/Desktop/CEA/Icon')

>>> OSError: Path is incorrect. It does not lead to a file, nor to a directory
```

Why doesn't this happen? And what should I do to rectify it and exclude these nodes from the list of nodes generated by Node.getChilds?

Comment: after you set self.name and before you check for file or dir can you add "print(path, os.stat(path))" and show what the output is

Comment: Also is there anywhere else that the value of self.type might be modified or changes?

Comment: The missing getter methods might hold the key.

Comment: @Keith I have added the getter methods (but there aren't used in my problem)

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure if it included a `@property` for the `type`. Seems not.

Comment: What does `ls -l /Users/alexandrejewell/Desktop/CEA/Icon` show you?

Comment: I have found the solution! The name is 'Icon\r', which means that there was a control character. I choose to exclude all nodes whose names used a control character with the method curses.ascii.iscntrl